# Which is the most precise command to get processes and system information?

Tags: linux, process, ps, top, statistics

I'm trying to evaluate performances of some active processes of mine on linux.

Searching the internet I found that `ps` and `top` are the only command available for that.

More precisely [here](https://superuser.com/questions/451344/difference-between-ps-output-and-top-output), it says that `top` is the right command.

I need to use `top -b -n 1` beacause I need to parse the output and "grep" only some information from that.

However, the `top -b -n 1` output results to be very different with respect to the classic top output. This happens, I think, because the second one compute the average percentage of cpu and ram usage, whereas the first one makes a "snapshot" of the system at the time it has been launched.

Am I right? is the `top -b -n 1` output a valid response or a fake one? May I use it to compute some statistics or not?

is `top -b -n 1` a valuable command to get information about system and processes? are there any other commands or whatever else to evaluate performances on linux?

Comment: Can you post some data supporting your theory about `top` displaying very different values depending on whether the `-b` option is used or not ?

Comment: it really depends on what informations you want, please when you ask a question, try to explain your goal cleary and the different things you have try so far, so we can orientate you in the right direction if you're mistaken.

Comment: thank you all for answering. Naming performances and `top`,`ps` commands I thought was enough to understand what kind of information I need. Anyway, I need cpu and ram usage of some process and total ram and total cpu usage. My question aim to undestand if those commands are enough to get these information and, most of all, if they are the right tools. I will post an example about the differences of `top` and `top -b`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to evaluate performances of some active processes of mine on linux

It is rather vague what you mean when say "evaluate performances". What exactly do you want to get?

> Searching the internet I found that ps and top are the only command available for that

`perf` is also available. https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial.
`ps` can give you CPU utilization: `ps --format pid,pcpu,size,vsz,cmd`

> top -b -n 1 output results to be very different with respect to the classic top output

Look, 
1) top is an open source and you can take a look at the source code. http://procps.sourceforge.net/ 2) If you analyze how `top` works with strace in the batch mode and in the screen mode then you will see that they open the same files in /proc (you can read `man proc`):

```
open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/online", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/etc/toprc", O_RDONLY)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/.toprc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/proc", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/1/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 4
open("/proc/1/statm", O_RDONLY)         = 4
open("/proc/2/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 4
... some lines skipped by me ...
open("/proc/27004/stat", O_RDONLY)      = 4
open("/proc/27004/statm", O_RDONLY)     = 4
open("/proc/27006/stat", O_RDONLY)      = 4
open("/proc/27006/statm", O_RDONLY)     = 4
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 3
open("/proc/uptime", O_RDONLY)          = 3
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)         = 4
open("/proc/stat", O_RDONLY)            = 5
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY)         = 6
```

> is the top -b -n 1 output a valid response or a fake one

I took a look at the source code and see that the "-b" option only set Batch flag which affects how it display info, not how it calculate the numbers. So, please, check again your test

```
Batch = 0,          /* batch mode, collect no input, dumb output */
```